promoted query rules is not opening
i have SharePoint on promises 2019 when i add promoted query rules to show specific rosulates.
and create one page   add 2 webpart : search box and search results
when I'm searching it is showing promoted results but if i click on it it will return me again to search page and not opening a link
how to solve this issue
